# Ribbon buttons are always disabled in Site level ribbon tab

Tags: 2013, ribbon, site-level-ribbon

I have created one **Site level ribbon tab in SharePoint 2013** using Visual Studio. Basic requirement behind the site level ribbon is to show ribbon tab everywhere in the site like in wiki page, site pages, publishing pages and in all lists/libraries' views.

I have created site level ribbon using below reference urls:

- http://sharepointpals.com/post/Persistent-Site-level-Custom-Ribbon-Tab-in-SharePoint-2013
- http://tom-randomworks.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-site-level-ribbon-tabs.html

**My Problem:**

Ribbon tab is coming on all pages but all ribbon buttons are always disabled though I haven't added any code for disabling/enabling buttons.

Any help would be appreciated!